# How to hide the cursor permanently in Typed JS

Tags: javascript, typedjs

I want to hide the cursor permanently in TypedJS i.e. I don't want it to blink/show as it types. I have found some tutorials on how to hide it on complete but not how to hide it since beginning. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `showCursor` option.

```js
 var typedX = new Typed('#animatedText', {
  strings: 
    ['Hello Hello Hello',  'World World World', 'Goodbye Goodbye Goodbye'],
  showCursor: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js"></script>

<div id="animatedText"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `typed::after` from css will help.

```
.typed::after {
    content: '|';
    display: inline;
    -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
    animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
}
```

You can try it [here](https://codepen.io/merb/pen/yOwJjj).